# Trouble installing Yeoman

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

Hello all I am attempting to install Yeoman however when I attempt to install the package via npm I get the following error.

```
sudo npm install -g yeoman
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yeoman
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yeoman
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yeoman/-/yeoman-0.9.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yeoman/-/yeoman-0.9.1.tgz
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/yeoman/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/nodeunit/node_modules/tap/node_modules/runforcover/node_modules/bunker/node_modules/burrito/node_modules/.bin'
npm ERR! error rolling back  yeoman@0.9.1 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/yeoman/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/nodeunit/node_modules/tap/node_modules/runforcover/node_modules/bunker/node_modules/burrito/node_modules/.bin']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/yeoman/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/nodeunit/node_modules/tap/node_modules/runforcover/node_modules/bunker/node_modules/burrito/node_modules/.bin' }
npm ERR! Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/yeoman/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/nodeunit/node_modules/tap/node_modules/runforcover/node_modules/bunker/node_modules/burrito/node_modules/.bin'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yeoman"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/chris
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.9
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.61
npm ERR! path /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/yeoman/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/nodeunit/node_modules/tap/node_modules/runforcover/node_modules/bunker/node_modules/burrito/node_modules/.bin
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! errno 53
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/chris/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I have used node and npm before but I have never gotten an error like this.

Comment: Have you considered adding this as an issue to [Yeoman's GitHub repository](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues)?

Comment: Could you show us the output you get when you run the Yeoman audit script? curl -L get.yeoman.io | bash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got a `notempty` error when trying to remove a certain folder with `rmdir`. I'm not exactly sure why that is.. but..

```
rm -rf /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/yeoman
sudo npm install -g yeoman
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that later yesterday to no avail. Now when it installs it does fine. However the Yeoman installer can't find Yeoman in npm now.

Comment: I am trying to install Yeoman and I am struck with the same error even after trying rm -rf above command